# NServiceBus with Azure Service Bus, full duplex and multiple senders

Tags: azure, nservicebus

I have implemented a small sample project based on the AzureServiceBusFullDuplex sample from NServiceBus package (3.2.8) with a small difference - I have the listener in the cloud and sender on premises. It works OK until I run two on-premises endpoints. When I do that and second enapoint sends a message, reply is received by the first endpoint. When I initiate a third endpoint and it sends a message, reply is received by the second endpoint.

Logically I understand what happens, every endpoint gets subscribed to the reply message contract and the latest registered endpoint received all messages of that type. But how than could I implement my scenario when I have multiple senders of the same message type with only one handler in the cloud? It is something similar to sessions support in native Azure Service Bus queues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I completed my prototype using

1) No queue name specified in the AzureServiceBusQueueConfig

2) Specifying a queue name in the code

```
                _configure = Configure.With()
           .DefaultBuilder()
           .Log4Net(new log4net.Appender.ColoredConsoleAppender())
           .JsonSerializer()
           .DefineEndpointName(queueName)
           .AzureServiceBusMessageQueue()
           .IsTransactional(false)
           .MessageForwardingInCaseOfFault()
           .UseInMemoryTimeoutPersister()
           .DisableSecondLevelRetries()
           .InMemorySubscriptionStorage()
           .UnicastBus()
               .DoNotAutoSubscribe()
               .LoadMessageHandlers()
           .CreateBus();
```

In the AzureServiceBusQueueConfig.cs I found that it uses an endpoint name as a queue name and if no queue name is configured, endpoint name that comes from the preceding configuration call is used.

Answer (score 2):

Alexey,

sounds like the on premise endpoints are configured with the same input queue and first one to pick up the reply gets it, can you validate this and make sure they all listen on different queues?

Kind regards,
Yves

Comment: Yes, I actually just finished the POC couple of hours ago, splitting endpoints to different queues. I actually started at splitting manually in app.config and this worked, I look at the configuration section code and tries QueuePerInstance, but it only works if several instances run on the same machine, so I just left the queue name empty in the config and used DefineEndPointName("unique name") and it worked :)